# Jenkins Plugin Development - how to log in as a user

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to work on a plugin for Jenkins that requires access to the logged in user. It appears that when i'm running the `mvn hpi:run`, the Jenkins server that is spun up appears to have a user called 'Anonymous' without the option to login/logout etc.

As per the documentation on developing a plugin, i'm using the following settings `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n"`. Is there any way to enable user authentication on this spun up Jenkins Server?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being more of an administration task. Had to manually allow authentication on the server (i got a warning on the Manage Jenkins page). This allowed me to create users.